# Is there any package to use for LDAP search in .NET Core?

Tags: .net-core, active-directory, ldap, worker-service

I am writing a worker service in .NET Core 7 which retrieves OUs, Groups & Users from Active Directory. Is there any good package to use for retrieving the information from Active Directory?

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement

Comment: ⚠️️ Software recommendation questions are **off-topic** here for the reasons explained in #3 of [/help/on-topic](/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comment, you'll want to look at these inbuilt framework packages:

[System.DirectoryServices](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.DirectoryServices)

[System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement)

These are fully compatible with .NET Core, and you should be able to do almost anything pertaining to AD using just these packages.

Comment: They are compatible with .net core but have a windows dependency. I'm currently looking for a way to migrate my code which is using these classes

Comment: I'm using novell.directory.ldap.netstandard which doesn't have Windows dependency and it can works with multiple directory servers like Active Directory, Novell e Directory & Open LDAP.